# Laravel eloquent scope always returns a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have the following model:

```php
class EmailAddress extends Model
{
    public function scopePrimary($query)
    {
        return $query->firstWhere('is_primary', true);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function emailAddresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmailAddress::class);
    }
}

echo $user->emailAddresses()->primary()->get();
```

I would expect Laravel to return a model since `firstWhere()` essentially does `LIMIT 1` in the query but instead I always get a collection with one model. Am I doing something wrong? How to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have encountered a bug. In `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php` we read at line 278 function firstWhere() `return $this->where($column, $operator, $value, $boolean)->first();`. As you correctly point out, you shouldn't get a collection. Maybe split it up for now and let the shortcut aside. `return $query->where('is_primary', true)->first();`

Comment: On the other hand, it's a scope.How do you implement the scope in a controller?

Comment: I guess, the problem is a little different. I just checked the snippet, I provided, and it actually doesn't show all the relevant code (sorry for that). I use the scope on a `HasMany` relationship. At first glance, it _should_ work if you do it after the relationship but the query that is passed in, just adds the where statement to the constraints and seems to take care to retain the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilize the [hasOne of many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many):

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function primaryEmailAddress()
    {
        $this->hasOne(EmailAddresses::class)->ofMany([], function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_primary', true);
        });
    }
}
```